# I cannot just deploy a function with Serverless-framework 1.20.2

Tags: deployment, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I wanted to follow [these tips](https://serverless.com/blog/quick-tips-for-faster-serverless-development/)

and just redeploy my function, as the `serverless.yml` had not been changed.

However, it just hangs on the `Serverless: Uploading function` stage. Forever, apparently.

The whole deploy (with `sls deploy`) works, though slowly.

How can debug this, as there is apparently no error message?

EDIT

When I use `sls deploy` my project takes about 4 min and 15s to deploy.

It seems rather long to me, so I thought I would use `sls deploy function -f myFunction` instead, which is supposed to be much faster.

However, when I try `sls deploy function -f myFunction`, it seems to just hang forever on `Serverless: Uploading function: myFunction`.

I have no idea how to debug that.

It seems using 'verbose', with `Serverless: Uploading function: myFunction --verbose` does not make a difference, the messages returned are the same.

I will try to wait and see if, eventually, the function deploy completes...

Well, I waited, and it doesn't: after about 8 min 30s I get the following error message:

> Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
>       Connection timed out after 120000ms
>       Get Support --------------------------------------------
>        Docs:          docs.serverless.com
>        Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
>        Forums:        forum.serverless.com
>        Chat:          gitter.im/serverless/serverless
>       Your Environment Information -----------------------------
>        OS:                     linux
>        Node Version:           7.10.0
>        Serverless Version:     1.20.2

Another oddity: when hanging, it reads:

> Serverless: Uploading function: myFunction (12.05 MB)...

But the function itself is just 3.2 kB, and does not include any packages.

When I use `sls deploy`, the size displayed is the same:

> Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (12.05 MB)...

What could be wrong with my function deploy?

EDIT 2

As @dashmug hinted, there is a config issue in `serverless.yml`.

In the `functions` dir of my serverless project, I would like to have a common `package.json` and `node_modules`. Then each function could import modules as needed.

I tried to follow [the official guide](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/).

My `serverless.yml` is like so:

```
functions:
  myFunction:
    package:
      exclude:
        - 'functions/node_modules/**'
        - '!functions/node_modules/module1_I_want_to_include/**'
        - '!functions/node_modules/module2_I_want_to_include/**'
```

Now I get, with `sls deploy`:

> Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (31.02 MB)...

and the function works :)

However, with `sls deploy function -f myFunction`, I get:

> Serverless: Uploading function: dispatch (1.65 MB)...

It does upload in a reasonable time, but the function now gives the following error:

> Unable to import module 'functions/myFunction': Error

Comment: Not helpful enough of a reply to warrant an Answer, but might I highly recommend switching to [Apex](http://apex.run)? I've been using it for nearly a year and have had very few issues and those were entirely from me hacking in a feature I wanted. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will give it a shot

Answer (score 8):

Things I would look at:

1. Try comparing what happens between the two:

   `$ SLS_DEBUG=true sls deploy --verbose`

   and

   `$ SLS_DEBUG=true sls deploy function -f myFunction --verbose`
2. Check your serverless config (packaging, etc.) against your project structure. One red flag is that the function deploy is as big as the service deploy. This could be a misconfiguration problem.
3. Use `serverless package` to see how the package(s) are zipped. It can provide some clues.
4. Are you using any plugins which may have altered the way your package is created?
5. How many `node_modules` directory do you have? Do you have only one for the entire service or one for each function?

Comment: 1. that did not help, as the 'function only' deploy just hangs

Comment: 2. you are definitely on to something: it is probably a package config issue in the yaml

Comment: 3. yes, I could see two large packages: one called 'serverless.zip', the other 'myFunction.zip'

Comment: 4. no, no particular plugin was used for packing/packaging

Comment: 5. I am aiming for just one package for all functions, and would like to use exclude/include to get the modules needed within each function

Comment: 1. SLS_DEBUG was not meant to _fix_ it. But we might get a clue depending on what is shown on screen at the time it hangs.

3. Great. Now compare the contents of those two. Are the zip contents what you expect them to be? Does the myFunction.zip really contain only `myFunction`?

5. One package for all functions or one package for each function?

Comment: I would like one 'node_modules' for all functions; I edited my question with the latest developments, and an extract of the 'serverless.yml'

Answer (score 2):

You can make the deploy process more verbose by passing the `--verbose` argument to the deploy function.

Either `sls deploy --verbose` or `sls deploy -v` will do the trick.

Comment: thanks @JustDanyul. What I mean is: deploying the whole project takes a while, so I thought I would just upload the function that I had updated. I will edit the question to make it clearer...

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to figure out why function deployment (as opposed to service deployment) would hang. I may have misconfigured my `serverless.yml` file.

But no big deal: I can do without `sls deploy function -myFunction`.

Because my expectations were wrong. I thought deploying a function would be way faster than deploying a service, by somehow  not redeploying the `node_modules` directory.

But there is no partial function deployment in AWS: when a function is deployed, all necessary node modules must be deployed as well for the function to work.

As explained in [serverless doc](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/deploying/):

> The Framework packages up the targeted AWS Lambda Function into a zip file.
>
> The Framework fetches the hash of the already uploaded function .zip file and compares it to the local .zip file hash.
>
> The Framework terminates if both hashes are the same.
>
> That zip file is uploaded to your S3 bucket using the same name as the previous function, which the CloudFormation stack is pointing to.

I had (naively) hoped that only the updated handler would be uploaded to S3.
But as the function is packaged before deployment, it does need all of its modules and dependencies.

So the way I see it, function deployment would save time (as opposed to service deployment) only if the service has multiple functions, and the service functions do not use many common nodejs modules. And if `sls deploy function -f myFunction` does not hang, that is :)

---

So to increase development speed, the trick is to use offline emulation with a tool like [serverless offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline)

[serverless offline](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline) provides a local server, and lambda function `myFunction` becomes accessible locally, by calling `http://localhost:3000/myFunction` in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or the browser

In most cases, `sls deploy` can be called only once, after the handler has been thoroughly tested offline.